# Transform a List[(T, Double)] on a Json value with the play framework

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I'm writing a Play 2.3.2 application, using Scala.
I use ReactiveMongo to access a my mongoDB database.

I've a collection named recommendation.advices that store all the suggestion to the user.

A document has the following form:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54475f434be669af141677b7"),
    "id" : "b8e84cb9-4b3a-4c6c-b01d-af276747e4ad",
    "user" : {
        "id" : "",
        "email" : "luigi@gmail.com"
    },
    "output" : [
        {
            "tag" : "Vegetable:Carrots - alberto@gmail.com",
            "score" : 0
        },
        {
            "tag" : "Paper Goods:Liners - Baking Cups",
            "score" : 0
        },
        {
            "tag" : "Vegetable:Carrots - Jumbo",
            "score" : 0
        },
        {
            "tag" : "Paper Goods:Lialberto- Baking Cups",
            "score" : 0
        }
    ],
    "date" : 1413963587328,
    "type" : "system",
    "clicked" : true
}
```

Now I'm writing a method in my controller that returns all the data where `"clicked": true`, and I want to return a Json in the following form:

```
{"idR": "b8e84cb9-4b3a-4c6c-b01d-af276747e4ad",
"user" : {
        "id" : "",
        "email" : "luigi@gmail.com"
    },
    "tags" : [
        {
            "tag" : "Vegetable:Carrots - alberto@gmail.com",
            "score" : 0
        },
        {
            "tag" : "Paper Goods:Liners - Baking Cups",
            "score" : 0
        },
        {
            "tag" : "Vegetable:Carrots - Jumbo",
            "score" : 0
        },
        {
            "tag" : "Paper Goods:Lialberto- Baking Cups",
            "score" : 0
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I make that in play??

I try to implement the method as the following:

```
def clickedAdvises = Action.async {
       val query = Json.obj("clicked" -> true)
       Advices.find(query).toList flatMap { advices => 
         val results = for(el <- advices) yield Json.obj("idR" -> el.id, "user" -> el.user, "tags" -> el.output)
         Future{Ok(Json.obj("results" -> results))}

       }
     }
```

The el.output is a `List[(Tag, Double)],` and for the Tag I've defined a formatter.

But the compiler gives me the following errors:

```
[error] /Users/alberto/git/bdrim/modules/recommendation-system/app/recommendationsystem/controllers/StatisticsController.scala:111: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : List[(recommendationsystem.models.Tag, Double)]
[error]  required: play.api.libs.json.Json.JsValueWrapper
[error]              val results = for(el <- advices) yield Json.obj("idR" -> el.id, "user" -> el.user, "tags" -> el.output)
[error]                                                                                                              ^
[error] /Users/alberto/git/bdrim/modules/recommendation-system/app/recommendationsystem/controllers/StatisticsController.scala:111: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : List[(recommendationsystem.models.Tag, Double)]
[error]  required: play.api.libs.json.Json.JsValueWrapper
[error]              val results = for(el <- advices) yield Json.obj("idR" -> el.id, "user" -> el.user, "tags" -> el.output)
[error]                                                                                                              ^
[error] one error found
```

How can I fixed that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is self explanatory:

You need `JsValue`, instead you are giving a `List[(recommendationsystem.models.Tag, Double)]` which apparently is the type of `output` field in your `Advice` class.

The fact that you have a formatter for your `Tag` class does not change the situation, first because what you have is a List of tuples, not a single tag, second because formatter only works when you use `toJson` and `fromJson` macros.

So what you need is somehow convert this `List` of tuples to a `JsValue`.

`JsArray` is corresponding to JSON list. If you look at the code of it

```
case class JsArray(value: Seq[JsValue] = List()) extends JsValue
```

you see that you can pass a `Seq` of `JsValue`s to it. So you need to somehow convert a tuple of `(recommendationsystem.models.Tag, Double)` to a `JsObject` (which is corresponding to a JSON object). You can do this simply with the following code:

```
JsObject(Seq(
  ("tag", tag),
  ("score", score)
))
```

or by using the `Json.obj` which is a helper factory mehtod for constructing a `JsObject`.

So the code will be:

```
val results = for { 
                el <- advices
              } yield 
                Json.obj(
                  "idR" -> el.id, 
                  "user" -> el.user, 
                  "tags" -> Json.arr(el.output.map(it => Json.obj((it._1, it._2)).asInstanceOf[JsValueWrapper]): _*)
                        )
```

### Easier way!

If you refer to [Play Doc about JSON](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaJson) you will see that you can convert objects to/from json by using `play.api.libs.json.Json.toJson` method.
In order to do that you need an implicit writer for your classes which is pretty straightforward.

There are some macro helpers, for example `Json.writes` macro helps you create a writer for your class. This machinery is recursive so if you have implicit writers for all classes needed, then you can simply call `Json.toJson(advice)` and get the result.

So I would suggest to start writing an implicit writer for your advice class:

```
import play.api.libs.json._

implicit def adviceWriter = Json.writes[Advice]
```

then try

```
Json.toJson(advice)
```

Then compile the code, you will get compile errors because you need writer for all needed classes. Continue by providing a writer for them till you get no compile error!

This makes the code cleaner and more concise and focused, as the actual conversion to Json will not pollute the actual code. In addition, you can reuse the code without explicitly doing anything. You need just to bring implicit writers and readers to your context by importing them and using `Json.toJson` and `Json.fromJson` methods.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should transform  el.output to JsObject before insert it in you jsObject

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `el` object can be called by something like `el.id`? It's not JavaScript, even it's JsValue, it should called by `(el \ "id")`.

I'm no pretty sure, but try using `el(id)` to call it and insert as a value of your `JsObject` like

```
Json.obj("idR" -> el(id))
```

Comment: Advices.find(query).toList returns a Future[Advice], where Advice is a my type, so i use the method on the obeject to access at the Advice id, output, ecc..

Comment: I'm not using nothing JS notation

Comment: Are you using IDE like Scala IDE or Typesafe Activator? I recommend you to using IDE, it's very helpful I though. When you are in IDE, you can highlight your `el` value and exploring the clue that can help you with that. Because dot notation in Scala is used to call method or attributes, CMIIW.